# How to Reduce a set of equations for some subset of variables generic and nonzero?

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation

```
y + x z + c^2 z^3 (a - b) e == 0
```

that I want to `Reduce` for generic nonzero values of `a` and `b`. If I try

```
Reduce[y + x z + c^2 z^3 (a - b) e == 0 && And @@ Thread[{a, b} != 0],
  {c, x, y, z, e}]
```

then some of the conditions include the restriction `a==b`, which I want to exclude because I only want solutions with generic `a` and `b`.

If instead I use

```
SolveAlways[y + x z + c^2 z^3 (a - b) e == 0, {a, b}]
```

then the solution `e == (-y - x z)/((a - b) c^2 z^3)` is not found because it has (a - b) in the denominator and `SolveAlways` is considering the possibility that `a==b`.

The only solution I have at the moment is to use `Reduce` with the additional condition that `a!=b`. However, for more complicated situations where I want many variables to be generic and nonzero, I would have to include something like

```
And @@ Unequal @@@
  Subsets[{c12, c21, c31, d30, e11, f24, e}, {2}]
```

and `Reduce` just runs forever. And that only rules out the possibility that two of the variables have the same value; `Reduce` would still find more complicated relations among the variables I want to be generic.

This seems like the kind of thing Mathematica might already have built in functionality for. Is there a good way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `And @@ Unequal @@@ Subsets[{c12, c21, c31, d30, e11, f24, e}, {2}]` - you don't actually have to do this. `Apply[Unequal, Append[{c12, c21, c31, d30, e11, f24, e}, 0]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you, that is more concise! Although the main problem still stands.